# concatenate lists with subscripts, python

Tags: python, list

to update: use the @azro code and modify only the indexes of the for.
it doesn't mark me error with your answers, the code works fine, however I still don't get the expected result, I put my full code.

```
arch is dataframe
channels=['ch1','ch1']
targets=['op1','op2']
l=[]
m = []
n = []
for ch in channels:
    for tar in targets:
        for j in range(1,22):                                                        
            df=arch[(arch.Año.isin(año)) & (arch['Channel'] == ch) & (rcha['Week'] == j)]

           l.append(df[['time',tar]].set_index('time').rename(columns={'time' : 'time' + str(j)}))
        m.append(l)
     n.append(m)

a = []
for i in range(len(n)):
    for j in range(len(m)):
        for k in range(len(l)):
            a.append(n[i][j][k])
a = pd.concat(a, axis=1).reset_index()
```

by printing "a" I get

```
time | op1 | op1 |...| op2 | op2 |..| op1 | op1 | op2 |..| op2 
1    | 0.2 | 0.1 |   | 0.2 | 0.1 |..| 0.1 | 0.1 | 0.2 |..| 0.8
2    | 0.3 | 0.4 |   | 0.1 | 0.3 |..| 0.2 | 0.7 | 0.9 |..| 0.3
3    | 0.7 | 0.8 |   | 0.9 | 0.11|..| 0.4 | 0.8 | 0.7 |..| 0.8
```

I have it like this, because I have two elements in "channels" and two elements in "targets" and I need to print a table for "ch1 with op1", "ch1 with op2", "ch2 with op1", "ch2 with op2".

```
for ch1
time | op1 | op1 |..
1    | 0.2 | 0.1 |..  
2    | 0.3 | 0.4 |..
3    | 0.7 | 0.8 |

time | op2 | op2 |..
1    | 0.2 | 0.1 |..
2    | 0.1 | 0.3 |..
3    | 0.9 | 0.11|.. 


for ch2

time | op1 | op1 | ..
1    | 0.1 | 0.1 | ..
2    | 0.2 | 0.7 | ..
3    | 0.4 | 0.8 | ..

time | op2 |..| op2 
1    | 0.2 |..| 0.8
2    | 0.9 |..| 0.3
3    | 0.7 |..| 0.8
```

Comment: As the error states, `pd.concat` expects to concatenate multiple things, but you passed it a single DataFrame.  Perhaps `a = pd.concat(np.flatten(n), axis=1).reset_index()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
a=n[0][0][0]
for i in range(len(n)):
    for j in range(len(n)):
        for k in range(len(n)):
            if not i==j==k==0:
                a=pd.concat((a, n[i][j][k]),axis=1).reset_index()
```

'a' is your cumulative concatenation, so you then need to concatenate that with the next entry

Comment: thanks, your answer solves the error, but I still don't get the desired result, I have already updated my code to see if it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass multiple Dataframe to `concat` not just one, you'd better to it  in one-shot

```
a = []
for i in range(len(n)):
    for j in range(len(n)):
        for k in range(len(n)):
            a.append(n[i][j][k])
a = pd.concat(a, axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks, your answer solves the error, but I still don't get the desired result only the first two values ​​concatenate me, not all , I have already updated my code to see if it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want this:

```
import numpy as np
a = pd.concat(np.flatten(np.array(n)), axis=1).reset_index()
```

If this does not work, please share with us a small sample of your `n` array to make it work.

Comment: thanks, your answer solves the error, but I still don't get the desired result, I have already updated my code to see if it is clearer

Comment: @KLM Please provide a sample input `n` and desired output `a` so we understand better. The code you updated (which I assume does not achieve what you desire) does not make it clearer. Thank you. And what is `channels` and `arch` in your updated code? Please make it reproducible